# Make a table id its own foreign key entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I wanted to know if it was possible to create a table with an id, a label and a foreign key referring to the id of the table itself.
Below is the example of what I would like to do but that does not work because the `public virtual RubricFo` can not be called by itself.

```
public class RubricFO
{
   [Key, Required]
   public int IdRubricFO { get; set; }

   [MaxLength(250)]
   public string LabelRubricFO { get; set; }

   public bool IsActif { get; set; }

   public int RankDisplay { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("IdRubricFO")]
   public int IdRubricFO_Fk { get; set; }
   public virtual RubricFO RubricFO { get; set; }

   public int IdStructure { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("IdStructure")]
   public virtual Structures Structures { get; set; }
}
```

I do not know if I am clear enough if you need additional info do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please see this link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code

Comment: Thanks for the link it helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You see this if you want a Tree structure, where every node of the Tree has zero or more `SubNodes`, no `ParentNode` if it is a top node, or one `ParentNode` if it is a `SubNode`.

```
class Node
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Node has zero or more subNodes:
    public virtual ICollection<Node> SubNodes {get; set;}

    // every Node is the subNode of zero or one ParentNode, using foreign key
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}         // null if it is a Top Node
    public virtual Node Parent {get; set;}
}
```

I'm pretty sure, that this is enough information for entity framework to understand the relations.

If not, you can use fluent API in your `DbContext` to inform entity framework about the model

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     // build table Nodes:
     modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
         .HasKey(node => node.Id)                // not needed, I followed the conventions
         .HasOptional(node => node.Parent)       // every node table has an optional Parent
         .WithMany(node => node.SubNodes)        // every Parent Node has zero or more SubNodes
         .HasForeignKey(node => node.ParentId);  // the foreign key to the parent node
```

Nice exercise: try `int ParentId` instead of `int?`, a zero value could mean there is no parent.